# Python super() argument 1 must be type, not classobj

Tags: python

I have this code here:

```py
class foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.customers = {}
    def __getattribute__(self,attr):
        def get(a):
            return super(foo,self).__getattribute__(a)
        if len(get("customers").keys()) >= 1 or callable(get(attr)): 
            return get(attr)
        return None
    def addcustomer(self,name,itemsbought):
        customers=super(foo,self).__getattribute__("customers")
        customers[name] = {"bought":itemsbought}
        self.customers=customers
Shop = foo()
print Shop.customers
Shop.addcustomer("Bill",["Apple","Banana"])
print Shop.customers
```

But when i run this code i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 21, in <module>
    Shop.addcustomer("Bill",["Apple","Banana"])
  File "foo.py", line 14, in addcustomer
    customers=super(foo,self).__getattribute__("customers")
TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not classobj
```

Why am i getting this error? Did i pass wrong arguments to `super()`? I'm using Python 2.7

Comment: This obnoxious behaviour is one of the many reasons to move on to 3.x :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you did use super correctly. The first line:

```
class foo():
```

should be

```
class foo(object):
```

The reason for this is that your class is not a "new-style" class. `super()` only works on new style classes 

Reference: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/super

Answer (score 0):

```
super(foo,self).__getattribute__(a)
```

This is the old Python 2 way of using super. If you are learning Python, you should avoid Python 2 like the plague and only learn Python 3.

In Python 3, you do this instead:

```
super().__getattribute__(a)
```